# Python: change numpy array with NaNs to array with numbers and '--'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a numpy array with some floats and some nans:

```
a = [ 8.08970226  nan  nan  8.30043545  nan  nan   nan  nan]
```

I want to convert it to an array (for printing in Latex) to the mixed form:

```
a = ['8.08970226', '--', '--', '8.30043545', '--', '--', '--', '--']
```

The method I've worked out, which is not elegant, is:

```
a=a.astype('|S10')
a[a=='nan']='--'
a=list(a)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do the job? (I could probably stop at the second line for my Latex requirement.)

Advice apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy` [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([ 8.08970226,  np.NAN,  np.NAN,  8.30043545,  np.NAN,  np.NAN,   np.NAN,  np.NAN])
>>> np.ma.fix_invalid(a)
masked_array(data = [8.08970226 -- -- 8.30043545 -- -- -- --],
             mask = [False  True  True False  True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> print _
[8.08970226 -- -- 8.30043545 -- -- -- --]
```

or since you need it as that particular list:

```
>>> np.ma.fix_invalid(a).astype('|S10').tolist(fill_value='--')
['8.08970226', '--', '--', '8.30043545', '--', '--', '--', '--']
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but I need to intersperse ' &' elements for a Latex table,  and that adds complexity.

Comment: @dcnicholls I change it to save to a list, it's longer than your code but this seems like a job for *masked array*

Comment: That's a nice one-liner.  Thanks

Comment: You can also just use `np.ma.fix_invalid`.

Comment: @tiago that's much better, updated and community wikied since that's a much better way of doing it